# How to pass associative array to a php page in POST?

Tags: php, arrays, magento, associative-array

I am trying to use Magento 1.9 XmlConnect module to save the billing address function. In xml connect there is an action to do this, `saveBillingAddressAction`. In `savebillingaddressAction` method one line is trying to access an array from the POST variables like following -

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
```

How I can pass an array from client side to server side in POST variable so that `billing` param have the array with the needed data?

Magento repository - [CheckoutController.php](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/CheckoutController.php#L172).

Comment: `input name="billing[key]"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create arrays out of form elements using square brackets `[]`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="billing[]" value="billing-info1">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[]" value="billing-info2">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[]" value="billing-info3">
```

This will return a zero based array (ie `0=>'billing-info1',1=>'billing-info2'`, etc).

If you'd like to use an associative array you just need to create a key:

```
<input type="hidden" name="billing[key0]" value="billing-info1">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[key1]" value="billing-info2">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[key2]" value="billing-info3">
```

Then your return will be something like:

```
'key0' => 'billing-info1',
'key1' => 'billing-info2',
'key2' => 'billing-info3'
```